# MaxRecursion exceeded in TSQL sp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I have this code which works to a certain extent, but once there are too many records in the table it throws up the "recursive error message (over 100)"

My code counts the number of unique words in the column.  I have added the "option (maxrecursion 0) text but this has made no difference.  Can anyone help please?

I am using sql server 2005(!)

My sp is:

```
declare @table table(name varchar(50))
insert @table values('bla bla bla ltd')
insert @table values('bla plc ltd')
insert @table values('more text ')


declare @matchlist table(name varchar(50), replacement varchar(50))
insert @matchlist values('very good', 'good')
insert @matchlist values('good.', 'GOOD')
insert @matchlist values('nice.', 'NICE')
insert @matchlist values('-NICE', 'NICE')
insert @matchlist values('service.', 'SERVICE')
insert @matchlist values('GREAT.', 'GREAT')
insert @matchlist values('with.', 'WITH')
insert @matchlist values('WELL.', 'WELL')
insert @matchlist values('PROBLEMS.', 'PROBLEMS')

--query

select coalesce(m.replacement, a.substr) answer, count(*) count into #a
from [test_question] p

cross apply
(
  select substr from 
  dbo.f_split(p.answer, ' ')
) a 


left join
@matchlist m
on a.substr = m.name
where len(coalesce(m.replacement, a.substr))  >3
and coalesce(m.replacement, a.substr) not in ('they','with','have','been','were','house','from','isos','went','when','find','just','that','than','them','their','there')

group by coalesce(m.replacement, a.substr)

order by 2 desc

select * ,row_number()over (order by count desc) as ranking from #a
option (maxrecursion 0)
drop table #a
```

Comment: You properly need to find a non-recursive solution; and based on your information - I don't think this is a problem which should be recursive to begin with. But it would require information about your schema/data before an actual answer can be given, but to me it looks like you just need a normal join based approach

Comment: Thanks Allan.  I have just 2 columns in the table - an ID column and an "Answer" column which is 1000 rows (or so) of text based data - basically customer comments.  I am using the data to rank which words our customers are saying the most and mapping these in ssrs.  The recursion didn't show itself while I had 200 rows of test data in, but since this has increased I now have todays problem.  Do you have any advice based on this please?  Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 1):

You have placed `option (maxrecursion 0)` on a query which is not recursive. That's why it has no effect.

Probably, a function that you call is internally recursive. You must place `option (maxrecursion 0)` there.

Comment: Thanks usr.  This is all there is to the stored procedure, as, begin and set nocount on at the beginning, and an "END" at the end.  There is nothing else that I call or reference - I am at a loss now.  Cheers.

Comment: Thank you usr - sorted on the f_split, thanks for your time - easy fix!